# How do I use inline SVG in WordPress

Tags: posts

I am trying to put in an SVG inside my post, but it seems WordPress removes the content.

e.g.

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190">
 <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180"
 style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
 </svg>
```

Gets rendered to

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190"></svg>
```

Is it possible to do this without a plugin like raw_plugin

Comment: Appearantly not. The content area of posts and pages gets thoroughly filtered. Depending on the context however, it would be simple to create custom post meta that renders whatever you like.

Comment: I look forward to seeing an answer, HTML5 is totally not "here" yet. Native cross browser support for SVG is far from reality yet without using something like Raphael. http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=47), if you put all the svg block in **one line**, it will be rendered.

This should work:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190"> <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;"> </svg>
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link the answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer here stand alone.